# Error in R - Error in model.frame.default(terms(reformulate(attributes(Terms)$term.labels))

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am having this issue with random forest throwing an error.

I have this dataframe which contains tweet data that is already in a matrix form with a sentiment column which I am trying to predict.

```
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  2155 variables:
 $ anoth                          : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cancel                         : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ flight                         : num  2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ hold                           : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ hour                           : num  2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ive                            : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

This is my randomForest that is throwing error.

```
# convert to factor
dtm.df$sentiment <- as.factor(dtm.df$sentiment)

# create a decision tree model
model_rf <- randomForest(formula = sentiment ~ .,
                         data = dtm.df[train,],
                         importance = T, do.trace = F)

Factor w/ 2 levels "negative","positive": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

[1] negative negative negative negative negative negative negative negative
   [9] negative negative negative negative negative negative negative negative
```

The error I get is the following

```
Error in model.frame.default(terms(reformulate(attributes(Terms)$term.labels)),  : 
  type (special) incorrect variable 'next'
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out with this

Comment: Which *specific command* throws the error??

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution that worked for me.

Basically, I had to change the names of each of the attributes/features and append "_c" to the end. This has fixed the error and random forest worked just fine.

```
colnames(dtm.df) <- paste(colnames(dtm.df), "_c", sep = "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `randomForest(predictors,decision)` instead of `randomForest(decision~.,data=input)`. It's more efficient and less error prone, since the data doesn't need to be copied over.

more info: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37370/random-forest-computing-time-in-r